# Is this lying or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

Aslamualaikom,
I have with the help of a freight forwarder (agent) purchased products from China. As i live i  the EU i have to pay taxes and duties for the products. Before shipping the products you have to declare the amount you want for your product. The government wants that i declare the total value of the product and shipping and insurance all included.
I have asked my agent to declare the value as they know more than me. However they can be committing a Fraud or lying of the declared amount.

Am I helping them in sin as i have used the freight forwarder and is this haram?
Or better that i avoid this. Or is it not haram.
Apreciate any help.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the stackexchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Like any library, Islam Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice or legal verdicts, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your Mufti, Imam, or other trustworthy Counselor.